# Force Footer Into articleBody Wrapper in Joomla

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, height

I need to place my footer inside of the Joomla automatically added class articleBody and .item-page that wraps my article content. The footer is currently loaded after the article message in my index.php with the pages themselves being generated in the back-end of Joomla, hence the automatic wrapper. Therefore the footer is not wrapped in the .item-page with the rest of the article.

The reason for this is because the footer goes over all the other DIVs on the page except the first DIV. All of the DIVs are set at 100% height including the articleBody and .item-page which are generated by Joomla. It has to be this way to get the effect. For the record I am using Bootstrap 3 and loading it correctly.

After spending hours in the DOM I realized if I could drop my  tag into the .item-page wrapper with the body of the article, it would fit at the bottom as it should. Preferably, I won't have to code the footer into each and every page as that would be disastrous from an editing standpoint.

If anyone is curious, I am very eager to solve this so I'd be happy to chat about this and post the results here to help others who may have this issue in the future.

No, position absolute trying to force it to the bottom does not work.

**HTML - INDEX.PHP**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
                data-toggle="collapse" 
                data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav" style="html5" />
        </div>
    </nav>


    <jdoc:include type="message" />
    <jdoc:include type="component" />

<!--END CONTAINER-->
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row footer-container footer-row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="footer-logo">Logo</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <p class="footer-about">
                    About
                </p>
                <p class="footer-text">
                    Footer content here
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <p class="footer-about">
                    Contact Info
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </footer>
```

**HTML - IN CODE EDITOR OF THE AFFECTED PAGE**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="landing-bkg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class ="col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                <h1>Headline</h1>
                <h3>Subhead</h3>
                <div class="btn">
                    <p>Button</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- END COL -->
        </div>
        <!-- END ROW -->
    </div>
    <!-- END LANDING BKG-->

    <div id="another2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2 class="center">Headline</h2>
                <h3 class="center">Subhead</h3>
                <div class="btn btn-center">
                    <p class="center">Button</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- END COL -->
        </div>
        <!-- END ROW -->
    </div>
    <!-- END ANOTHER2-->

    <div id="another3-bkg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
                    <div class ="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <h2>Headline</h2>
                        <h3> Subhead</h3>
                        <div class="btn">
                            <p>Button</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END NESTED COLUMN -->
                </div>
                <!-- END NESTED ROW -->
            </div>
        <!-- END COL -->
        </div>
        <!-- END ROW -->
    </div>
    <!-- END ANOTHER3 BKG-->

    <div id="another4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2 class="center">Subhead</h2>
                <form>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Input Field" class="center-block">
                </form>
                <div class="btn btn-center">
                    <p class="center">Button</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- END COL -->
        </div>
        <!-- END ROW -->
    </div>
    <!-- ANOTHER 4 -->
</div>
<!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

**CSS**

```
/****HTML & BODY ****/

html,
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%; //Makes my DIVs 100% height, works great
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/****CONTAINER ****/
.container-fluid{
  height:100%;
}

/**** JOOMLA CLASSES I OVER RIDE TO GET THE DIVS AT 100% DOESN'T WORK WITHOUT IT ****/
.item-page{
  height:100%;
}
div[itemprop="articleBody"]{
 height:100% !important;
}


/**** FOOTER ****/

.footer-container{
    background-color:#565A5C;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
}

footer{
    position:relative;
}

.footer-row{
    width:100% !important;
    margin:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts? Would jQuery/JavaScript be the only way to move the <footer> element somewhere else in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with one line of jQuery. This is the only way it would work as it needs to be inside of the itemprop="articleBody" in order to fit within the 100% height containers.

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('footer').appendTo('div [itemprop="articleBody"]');
```